# I am unable to figure out how filter will work when we are using "keyword.name" in ng-model and in filter we are using "filter: keyword"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am unable to figure out how  filter will work only on the name in object not on the phone key in the object.As if we use only keyword in ng-model it will filter both name and phone in the object defined in the scope while in the case of the keyword.name it will filter out only name.

```
<script>

    var app = angular.module("app" , []);
    app.controller("controller" ,['$scope' , function($scope){

        $scope.answer = 1+2;
        $scope.object=[

        {name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
        {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
        {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
        {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
        {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
        {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]

    }]);

</script>
```

```
    <div ng-app = "app" ng-controller="controller" >

    <input type="text" ng-model="keyword.name" />

    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat = "item in object | filter: keyword" >

            <td> {{item.name}} </td>
            <td> {{item.phone}} </td>

        </tr>

    </table>



    </div>      



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you filter based only on keyword which is your ng-model, then angular by default adds a special property name that matches against any property. By default it is $. So technically filtering based on keyword as ng-model is same as filtering based on keyword.$. But if you append a property to the keyword it will overide angular's default special property name and filters based on your new key value.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: This means that when ng-model="keyword" then for angular it will be "filter: keywrod.$" or "ng-model=keyword.$" ? Actually i am getting confused with every new chpter in angular js

Comment: I think for angular, it will be "filter:keyword.$" .

Comment: but what's the logic behind it ? Can you explain it?

Comment: Angular will check if your ng-model has any property key, If it doesn't then it will match any property key of your ng-model object to find the filtered result.Basically $ is like a flag to check if the ng-model has any property key or not.If you specify a property key for your ng-model, then it will check for the expression that you want to filter only against that particular property key.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing object(keyword) as an expression  in filter to select from the array. you have declared only one property of object **keyword.name**. You have to see filter:keyword as  filter:{**name**:"this value will be item.name"}. So this  return the array items with a name only.

for example of if you had  ng-model="**keyword.dance**". then have to see filter:keyword as  filter:{**dance**:"this value will be item.dance"}. As here their will be no match so you will get blank result.

Comment: actually filter: keyword is giving valid result. I understand that filter: {Object} can also give the same result.  check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for example